# How to run Laravel Dusk to scrape web sites in a Docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

I'm using Dusk 5.1.

My objective is to use Dusk to scrape external sites in production.  Nothing excessive, just a few RSS feeds and maybe forum threads.  My app runs in my own docker-compose stack (not Laradock or anything) in `production`.

> I am not registering the `DuskServiceProvider` and thus am not exposed to risk in `production`.

Here's the problem:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException  : Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"w3c":false,"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless","--no-sandbox","--verbose"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
```

Here's the `Browser.php` I'm using rather than the one that comes with Dusk for testing purposes:

```php
/**
 * Reporting browser for console commands
 */
class Browser
{
    /**
     * @var \Laravel\Dusk\Browser
     */
    private $browser;

    public function browse(Closure $callback)
    {
        if (!$this->browser) {
            $this->browser = $this->newBrowser($this->createWebDriver());
        }
        try {
            $callback($this->browser);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        if ($this->browser) {
            $this->closeBrowser();
        }
    }

    protected function closeBrowser()
    {
        if (!$this->browser) {
            throw new Exception("The browser hasn't been initialized yet");
        }

        $this->browser->quit();
        $this->browser = null;
    }

    protected function newBrowser($driver)
    {
        return new DuskBrowser($driver);
    }

    /**
     * Create the remote web driver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function createWebDriver()
    {
        return retry(5, function () {
            return $this->driver();
        }, 50);
    }

    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = new ChromeOptions();
        $options->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--verbose',
        ]);
        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
        $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515', $capabilities
        );
    }
}
```

Then in my application I'm using:

```php
$defaultBrowser = app(Browser::class);
$defaultBrowser->browse(function (\Laravel\Dusk\Browser $browser) use ($feed) {
    $pageSoure = $browser->visit($this->feedUrl())
        ->driver->getPageSource();

    preg_match('/(<rss.+?<\/rss>)/is', $pageSoure, $matches);

    $feed->fromContents($matches[0]);
});
```

**What I'm unsure of is what steps I need to take to get this to correctly start the chrome driver within my container.**

> Note: There are guides online to use Laravel Dusk with Docker that rely on Selenium.  Doing so introduces concurrency issues with my app because they require running Selenium as a standalone service which leads to session issues when multiple jobs use it at the same time.

**My docker-compose**
I'm not sure why this would be relevant, but some folks asked for it.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: infrastructure/web/Dockerfile
    image: registry.gitlab.com/namespace/project:web
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./infrastructure/web:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    links:
      - redis
      - db
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  frontend-dev:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/namespace/project:web
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
  queue:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: infrastructure/cli/Dockerfile
    image: registry.gitlab.com/namespace/project:cli
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    command: php /var/www/html/artisan horizon
    links:
      - redis
      - db
  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
  ngrok:
    image: wernight/ngrok
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.3
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxxx
      MYSQL_USER: xxxxxx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
```

Comment: please post your Dockerfile/docker-compose in the question

Comment: Please try `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub` instead of `http://localhost:9515`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir `Failed to connect to localhost port 4444: Connection refused`

Comment: @LinSel I'm updating to include my docker-compose, though I don't understand why that's necessary when Dusk installs the dependency locally on my container, it's not running as a separate service, but the executable is located at `vendor/laravel/dusk/bin/chromedriver-linux`

Comment: Is Selenium definitely running?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Dusk doesn't use selenium, just chrome driver - https://github.com/laravel/dusk/commit/b17d0d0d5d472b47225143d26be46288d2ed03d8#commitcomment-34103801

Comment: (I wrote that comment.) That's why I'm asking. Your custom Dusk implementation doesn't seem to start the ChromeDriver. Are you starting it manually?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir My app is mirroring everything in the `DustTestCase` which doesn't include starting that process.  I couldn't find in Laravel/Dusk any evidence of it actually starting that process.

Comment: Dusk starts the process in `TestCase`: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/5.0/src/TestCase.php https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/5.0/src/Chrome/SupportsChrome.php

Comment: `startChromeDriver()` is never called there.  I'm also mirroring the `RemoteWebDriver::create` as demonstrated in the `Browser` class I provided, but it doesn't seem to start any process.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/5.0/stubs/DuskTestCase.stub

Comment: I do the same thing in my own `Browser`